# using Document.ready with update panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, document-ready

I have **J Query** events is assigned in **`document.ready`**, my page is also have **`update panel`**. when **`partial post back`** is happened in the page, I loss **`J query events.`**
is there Conflict between **`document.ready`** and **`update panel`**? how can I solve that?

Comment: @Aristos, kindly check title now. does it valid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

document.ready function will not work after a call back .. you need to call that function after every post back.. there are number of solutions

1) use pageLoad instead of document.ready

```
 function pageLoad() {
 //execute code
 }
```

2) or you can register your function after a call back

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, GetType(String), "function",      "try{function();}catch(err){}", True)
```

3) or you can call your function in

```
    function page_EndRequest(sender, args) {
     // your Code
     }
```

Comment: This will not work when navigated from a back button since the content will be served from the cache and the server will not fire those handlers.

Answer (score 1):

The `Update Panel` and `J Query` often prevent each other to work together. In your case the solution is you need to `rebind your J Query event` after the partial post back from Update Panel

try this

```
var prmInstance = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prmInstance.add_beginRequest(function () {        
        //re-bind jquery events 
    });

    prmInstance.add_endRequest(function () {
        //re-bind jquery events 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your document.ready function to below

```
Sys.Application.add_load(clickUpdate); //It work as document.ready function

function clickUpdate() {

/*Do stuff*/

}
```